# Picard–Lindelöf theorem conditions not met with unique IVP solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

According to [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), for $E$ Banach space and $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb R \times E$, the IVP
$$\begin{cases}
y^\prime(t) = f(t,y(t))\\
y(x_0)=y_0
\end{cases}$$

has a unique local solution providing that $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in $y$ and continuous in $t$.

Is there an example of $f(y)$ being continuous in $\mathbb R$, $\mathcal C^1$ in $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, not differentiable in $0$ ($f^\prime(0)=\infty$), but such that the IVP
$$\begin{cases}
y^\prime(t) = f(y(t))\\
y(0)=a
\end{cases}$$ has a unique solution?

Note: the existence of a solution is provided by Peano existence theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take 
$$
\begin{cases}
y'(t) = 1 + \sqrt{\lvert y(t) \rvert}
\\
y(0) = a,
\end{cases}
$$
where $a$ is arbitrary.  The unique solution $[t \mapsto \varphi(t)]$ is given in the implicit form
$$
t = \int\limits_{a}^{\varphi(t)} \frac{d\eta}{1 + \sqrt{\lvert \eta \rvert}},
$$
whereas $f(y) = 1 + \sqrt{\lvert y \rvert}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, and not differentiable at $y = 0$.